# Fire bug / Chrome Console to manually invoke a function

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firebug, firebug-lite

I am having a page with many button's , I have to Click on each button to Activate a user which takes a lot of time . I was wondering if Is it possible to invoke a link through Firefox / Chrome  console ?

For instance suppose there is  a Class

```
<a class="Button" href="#" link="/info.php?code=379645838760724 id="uqyiqh_25">
<span class="ButtonText">Click Here to activate user Greg</span></a>
```

I want to fire the link part of the  tag with the help of console ?
Can I use the Console to select this ID and Call the Link ?

Comment: If a `GET` at that link will activate the user you could dump the page source to a file, perform a little regexp magic to extract the links, then feed them to a batch process using `wget` or `curl`

Comment: Why is the url in a link attribute? And you're missing the terminating `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Button');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {  
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  request.open('GET', elements[i].href, true);
  request.send();
}
```

Comment: ooh! I like this one if it works with the OP's setup! :D +1 good sir.

Comment: I am getting an Error : TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'forEach'

Comment: `NodeList` objects don't have a forEach method? I've updated it.

Comment: @ddlshack - Its giving me just Undefined :) ? Do i need to change the href to link ?

Comment: Well no, you need to change link to href in your markup. And close the attribute. Afaik, link isn't a valid attribute for an anchor tag.